# Pros and Cons of using XML column to store datasets when logging to SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, logging, sql-server-2014

I am working on logging to a SQL table *(i.e. column names LogTime, SPROC, and Parameters)* for a application running in .Net 4.5 framework and am curious to know others input on the pros and cons of using an XML column to store parameters. Using XML will be highly beneficial when storing user defined table types however I would like to know am I overlooking something.

Thanks in advance for all comments and help.

Comment: MS SQL 2014, apologize for the ambiguity. @marc_s

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704064/what-is-the-best-way-to-save-xml-data-to-sql-server

Comment: Also this can be useful, though for SQL Server 2016 and above: https://hackernoon.com/xml-vs-json-shootout-which-should-i-use-in-sql-server-7eefa4dc7553

Comment: Related: [How would storing XML in a relational database violate Normalization Principles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39516417/how-would-storing-xml-in-a-relational-database-violate-normalization-principles)